# Ant design TimePicker wirhout content

Tags: next.js, antd, ant-design-pro

The timePicker open witout any time [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWwXI.png)

```
<TimePicker
                        ref={ref}
                        suffixIcon={null}
                        popupClassName={styles.DatePopup}
                        className={`${styles.FormInput} w-100 px-2 py-1 rounded-5`}
                        disabledTime={disabledTime}
                        placement="topRight"
                        size="small"
                        inputReadOnly
                        minuteStep={30}
                        hideDisabledOptions
                        getPopupContainer={trigger => trigger.parentElement}
                        open={true}
                        onClick={onToggle}
                        onBlur={onClose}
                        onOk={onClose}
                        allowClear
                        showSecond={false}
                        format={BASE_FORMAT_TIME}
                        placeholder="Время"
                    />
```

When I click on field the timePicker open and I can choose time

Comment: This can be due to your custom CSS or BASE_FORMAT_TIME, just have a look